# Query DateTime field using Date only in FileNet Content Engine

Tags: date, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet-cpe, filenet-ce-sql

Is it possible to query using only a Date field such as '`2017-03-02`' in IBM FileNet?

I have tried the below statement and it doesn't seem to work

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Name 
WHERE EstimatedDate = '2017-03-02'
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Name 
WHERE EstimatedDate <= DATE '2017-03-02'
```

I tried including TIMESTAMP and the below query works but i want to search only by using date such as `'2017-03-02'`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Name 
WHERE EstimatedDate <= TIMESTAMP '2017-03-02T00:00:00.000Z'
```

Comment: Using cast gives me query syntax error

Answer (score 4):

To search for a particular date you need to use a range between two timestamps: start of the target day and start of the next day. For today's date the query will be:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Name 
WHERE EstimatedDate >= 20180420T000000Z AND EstimatedDate < 20180421T000000Z
```

Please note that the timestamps above assume the UTC time zone (hence `000000Z`). If your task is supposed to handle time zones, the timestamps should be adjusted accordingly. For example, for `Europe/Rome` (current time zone offset `+02:00`) that would be

```sql
EstimatedDate >= 20180419T220000Z AND EstimatedDate < 20180420T220000Z
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [IBM FileNet P8, Version 5.2 
 - SQL Syntax reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/query_sql_syntax_rel_queries.htm)"

```
<literal> ::= <string_literal> | <integer> | <float> | 
              <ISO datetime> | <W3C datetime> | TRUE | FALSE | UNKNOWN | <guid>

<ISO datetime> ::= YYYYMMDDThhmmss[,ffff]Z
<W3C datetime> ::= YYYY-MM-DD[Thh:mm:ss[.ffff]][<timezone>]
```

Thus, in FileNet P8 do not use `timestamp` or `date` keywords,  but only the date you have written in one of these formats, and note - without an apostrophe sign!

You can find examples in a free book [Developing Applications
with IBM FileNet P8 APIs](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247743.pdf), for example on a page 73 there is `Example 3-30` :

```
// Construct the sql statement
SearchSQL sql = new SearchSQL(
"select ISTOStartDate, ITSOEndDate, ITSOVehicle " +
"from ITSOIdleActivity " +
"where “ +
"ITSOVehicle = OBJECT('{D5DC8C04-2625-496f-A280-D791AFE87A73}') " +
"AND ITSOStartDate < 20090801T000000Z OR " +
"ITSOEndDate > 20090701T000000Z" );
```

As you see, the date in this example is written directly without any apostrophes as: `20090701T000000Z` using `<ISO datetime>` format, you can also use another format: `2009-07-01`